# Can I configure Visual Studio's "Find all references" to ignore <cref/> comment references?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2015

When I add comments that call out another method, I'd like to use  tags in my XML so that I get auto-refactor freebies like naming updates, intellisense tooltip, etc.

However, I **don't** want these references to be considered "true" references, as far as the "Find all references" feature in Visual Studio goes.

Is there a way I can prevent  references from appearing in the "Find symbol results" Visual Studio window?